# Как работает конструкция match?

Tags: rust

Нужно запросить у пользователя ввод. Если он ввёл "ls", то нужно напечатать "один", если "sh" - "два"

```
let mut guess = String::new();

io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
    .expect("Не удалось прочитать строку");

let sh="sh".to_string();
let ls="ls".to_string();

match guess {
    ls => println!("один"),
    sh => println!("два"),
 }
```

Почему этот код печатает "один" в любом случае, что бы не ввёл пользователь?

Comment: А причем тут `match` ? У вас нигде нет условия, что выводить по вводу пользователем.

Comment: @And ну пользовательский ввод оказывается в строке `guess`, которая и является условием

Comment: А ну да все верно, не туда глянул. `match` же и есть `switch`. Точняк. Ну тогда попробуйте обрамить в `match` кавычками - `"ls"` и `"sh"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match guess {
    ls => println!("один"),
    sh => println!("два"),
}
```

В данном коде, `ls` и `sh` являются новыми
переменными, а не ссылаются на предыдущие.  О чём, собственно, и пишет
компилятор:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> ./tmp.rs:13:9
   |
12 |         ls => println!("один"),
   |         -- matches any value
13 |         sh => println!("два"),
   |         ^^ unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: #[warn(unreachable_patterns)] on by default
```

Можете написать так:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut guess = String::new();

    std::io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("не удалось прочитать строку");

    let guess = guess.trim();

    match guess {
        "ls" => println!("один"),
        "sh" => println!("два"),
        _    => println!("error"),
    }
}
```